# Event Hub metrics shows lots of "Other Errors", how to get details?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-monitoring

So I have created an Event Hub using the new portal. When I visit the Event Hub blade and browse to the Metrics blade in the Monitoring section I get this chart:

[image]

I wonder where I can find more info about these errors. Does anybody know?

Answer (score 1):

Event Hubs can also emit Diagnostic Logs, which contain detailed diagnostic information on errors. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-overview-of-diagnostic-logs#how-to-enable-collection-of-diagnostic-logs for how to enable these logs on your Event Hub. Once they are enabled, you can browse them in your Storage Account or send them into Log Analytics to view them.

Comment: I have enabled logging to blob storage but it does not contain anything related to any error.