# How to find out details about metrics "Internal Server Errors" and "Other Errors" for Azure EventHub

Tags: azure-eventhub

In the new Azure portal I see under "Metrics" section for an EventHub that there were many "Internal Server Error" events on a specific day. Is it possible to find out more about what could have caused it and description about those errors?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event Hub metrics shows lots of "Other Errors", how to get details?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40695596/event-hub-metrics-shows-lots-of-other-errors-how-to-get-details)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the metrics for Event Hubs state about **InternalServerErrors** and **OtherErrors**:

> **InternalServerErrors**: Total number of internal server error exceptions sent back to the sender or receiver while performing run-time operations. This type of error is due to either service-side or network problems.
>
> **OtherErrors**: These types of errors are due to faults at the sender or receiver side, such as providing bad parameters, not enough credentials, or trying to perform an operation on a nonexistent entity.

I would recommend you log into azure portal, choose your Event hub, click "MONITORING > Diagnostics logs", then turn on diagnostics for collecting logs. For more details, you could refer to [Event Hubs diagnostic logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-diagnostic-logs).

Comment: Thank you for the description as well. I did find the link after I posted the question, but this is useful anyway for the future reference.